# Jenkins slave throws InterruptedException on git pull or fetch via sh, those operations work via checkout

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, pipeline

I'd like to have a jenkins job which will perform merging a two branches of my chosing, on a list of repositories. Here's my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
agent any

parameters {
    text(name: 'REPOSITORIES', description: 'List of repository URLs (one per line)', defaultValue: 'https://git.xxx.com')
    string(name: 'SOURCE_BRANCH', description: 'Source branch to merge', defaultValue: 'Branch_sourceBranch')
    string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', description: 'Target branch to merge into', defaultValue: 'Branch_targetBranch')
}

stages {
    stage('Merge Branches') {
        steps {
            script {
                def repositories = params.REPOSITORIES.tokenize('\n')
                for (repository in repositories) {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/\${SOURCE_BRANCH}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'GITHUB_TOKEN_123', url: repository]]])
                    sh "git reset --hard" // just for test
                    sh "git checkout \${TARGET_BRANCH}"
                   // sh "git fetch"  - also fails
                    sh "git merge origin/\\${SOURCE_BRANCH}"
                    sh "git push origin"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

However, while running it, I am getting an error for any operations called via sh, which call remote repo, i.e git pull, git fetch, git push, here error log from the execution which fails at "sh git push origin" part of my pipeline:

```
14:33:52  Running on jenkins-slave-prg-xldzf in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/XXX/Merge_project
14:33:52  [Pipeline] {
14:33:52  [Pipeline] stage
14:33:52  [Pipeline] { (Merge Branches)
14:33:52  [Pipeline] script
14:33:52  [Pipeline] {
14:33:52  [Pipeline] checkout
14:33:53  The recommended git tool is: NONE
14:33:59  using credential GITHUB_TOKEN_123
14:33:59  Cloning the remote Git repository
14:34:02  Cloning repository https://git.xxx.com
14:34:02   > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/XXX/Merge_project # timeout=10
14:34:02  Fetching upstream changes from https://git.xxx.com
14:34:02   > git --version # timeout=10
14:34:02   > git --version # 'git version 2.39.3'
14:34:02  using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
14:34:02   > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://git.xxx.com +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
14:34:05   > git config remote.origin.url https://git.xxx.com # timeout=10
14:34:05   > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
14:34:06  Avoid second fetch
14:34:06  Checking out Revision 590162cae7effe128609425879eb595ca64aa948 (refs/remotes/origin/Branch_sourceBranch)
14:34:06   > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/Branch_sourceBranch^{commit} # timeout=10
14:34:06   > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
14:34:06   > git checkout -f 590162cae7effe128609425879eb595ca64aa948 # timeout=10
14:34:07  Commit message: "testCommit change 1"
14:34:07   > git rev-list --no-walk 590162cae7effe128609425879eb595ca64aa948 # timeout=10
14:34:07  [Pipeline] sh
14:34:08  + git reset --hard
14:34:08  HEAD is now at 590162ca testCommit change 1
14:34:08  [Pipeline] sh
14:34:08  + git checkout Branch_targetBranch
14:34:08  Previous HEAD position was 590162ca testCommit change 1
14:34:08  Switched to a new branch 'Branch_targetBranch'
14:34:08  branch 'Branch_targetBranch' set up to track 'origin/Branch_targetBranch'.
14:34:08  [Pipeline] sh
14:34:08  + git merge origin/Branch_sourceBranch
14:34:08  Updating 91102452..590162ca
14:34:08  Fast-forward
14:34:08   testFile/test.xsd | 1 +
14:34:08   README.md                                              | 3 ++-
14:34:08   2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
14:34:08  [Pipeline] sh
14:34:29  Cannot contact jenkins-slave-prg-xldzf: java.lang.InterruptedException
```

Is there something else I need to configure for sh git calls so they won't end up in java.lang.InterruptedException? Servers are not under any big load, I assume it has something to do with all operations calling remote repos, while git checkout, git reset work because they do not operate on remote repos?

Comment: Are your credentials set up properly?  You'd probably get this failure if Git timed out due to waiting for some sort of input, such as credentials.

Comment: @bk2204 Previous git fetch and clone works properly, the one launched via  checkout([$class: 'GitSCM' (...), so I assume nothign is wrong with credentials

Comment: The `git push` subcommand appears to be missing the branch argument.

Comment: upstream is set on that branch so git push origin is enough